# linear layout elements not taking up whole screen

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have a small linearlayout with another linearlayout that has some errors when i add weights to it and try for it to take up the whole screen. Please check my code and help me out.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:orientation="horizontal"

    android:id="@+id/linear_layout_two"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear_layout_one"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textColor="#3193b9"
            android:text="99.3%"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/goals_accuracy"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Goals accuracy"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/goals_accuracy_2"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/the_vertical"

        android:id="@+id/imageView8" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textColor="#3193b9"
            android:text="10:30hr"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/total_time_on_ice"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:text="Total time on ice"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/total_time_on_ice_2"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried adding weights to it but it didnt work, so i removed it. Although i do know that i have to set the width to 0 and set weights to 1 but I am confused on how to make it work on nested layouts. However, i was able to make work on a single linearlayout ...

Comment: your problem is that your 2 sub linearlayout don't take the whole parent width?

Comment: Yup, all the things inside every layout to fill thw whole width of the screen equally, the imageview in between these two layouts is just a vertical line image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_two"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear_layout_one"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:textColor="#3193b9"
                android:text="99.3%"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/goals_accuracy"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Goals accuracy"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/goals_accuracy_2"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:textColor="#3193b9"
                android:text="10:30hr"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/total_time_on_ice"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:text="Total time on ice"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/total_time_on_ice_2"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I've dropped ImageView, add a background that render a right border to your fisrt `LinearLayout`

Short explanation:

I have assigned to each LinearLayout an equal weight of 1. So they have half parent width each one. And added width=0dp because you have an horizontal parent LinearLayout, so you must set to 0 sons width.

The ImageView instead is not useful, you can achieve border goal as I explained. By this way you can also simplify your xml

Comment: it works !! can you please explain what you did ...?

Answer (score 0):

Some notes:

- Why are your ImageView elements 0 width?
- The TextView elements having `android:layout_weight="1"` should have 0 height

It should solve your problem.

Comment: I read an answer on stackoverflow and tried but it didnt quite work :/